# How can I add an image as a pdf header?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf-generation, itext

I am using the code below to generate a pdf. Is there a way I can point to an image and use that as the header? "~/images/Header.png"? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", random)
    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))
    Dim ev As New itsEvents
    pdfWrite.PageEvent = ev

    Doc1.Open()
    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))

    Doc1.Close()
End Sub
Public Class itsEvents
    Inherits PdfPageEventHelper
    Public Overrides Sub OnStartPage(ByVal writer As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, ByVal document As iTextSharp.text.Document)
        Dim ch As New Chunk("This is my Header on page " & writer.PageNumber)
        document.Add(ch)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I did a search for "adding images pdf itextsharp" and this was the first result: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/87/iTextSharp-Working-with-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath(".") & "/logo/Anjanlogo.jpg"
Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)
image.ScalePercent(24F)
doc.Add(image)
```

Note: The `24F` scaling comes from the fact that, by default, embedded images are 72 DPI and most commercial printers use 300 DPI, so 72/300 * 100 = 24%.

To move the image around the page you can use the `SetAbsolutePosition` method, like this:

```
image.SetAbsolutePosition(36F, 36F)
```

Note: `36F` is the margin of the PDF, so this will push the logo to the top left of the corner of the PDF, but still maintain the border.

Comment: how can i repeat this at every page..?